# MFC, How to get the element in CArray, which element type is CString

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, mfc, cstring

I am confuse in GetAT and aryString[n], as follow code

```
CArray <CString, CString> arySctring;
aryString.SetSize(3);

aryString.Add(_T("a1"));
aryString.Add(_T("a222"));
aryString.Add(_T("a3"));

TRACE(_T("%d %s"), aryString.GetCount(), aryString[0]);
```

the TRACE result is "6  ", it means aryString[0] is no data, I instead of aryString.GetAt(0), the result is same.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use as follow code to asign the element

```
aryString.SetAtGrow(0, _T("a"));
aryString.SetAtGrow(1, _T("a"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.SetSize(3);
```

reserve 3 "rooms". Calling

```
Add();
```

three times, reserve another 3 "rooms", hence you get 6 at count and your array is as follow:

```
"""""""a1""a222""a3"
```

.
To get the result I guess you want, once you've set size, you can do:

```
aryString.SetSize( 3 );
aryString[0] = "a1";
aryString[1] = "a222";
aryString[2] = "a3";
```

As side note, MFC provides you with CStringArray class, so you haven't to do:

```
CArray<CString,CString>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you do `aryString.SetSize(3);` `aryString` reserves 3 items with empty string. 
when you Add three new strings at the end , the item count of the array is 6. the first item is  empty string, `aryString.GetAt[3]` will return a1, function add will auto increase the size of the array ,you do not have to `SetSize(3)` to reserve space